# Restart cumsum and get index if cumsum more than value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say I have an array of distances `x=[1,2,1,3,3,2,1,5,1,1]`.

I want to get the indices from x where cumsum reaches 10, in this case, idx=[4,9].

So the cumsum restarts after the condition are met.

I can do it with a loop, but loops are slow for large arrays and I was wondering if I could do it in a `vectorized` way.

Comment: Hard to achieve by the vectorized method

Comment: hmmm looks like it @WeNYoBen

Comment: @yatu I think I answer those type question before :-) ...Better solution maybe using numba ..

Comment: If you want to reset `cumsum` whenever 10 is reached, something like this could work: `x.cumsum()%10`. If `x` is an array this is really fast. But also this may not work for you, because how you want to handle edge cases is unclear. Like, if `cumsum` is 11, should it reset to 0 or 1?

Comment: No @brenlla that doesn't quite work as it doesn't take into account the remainder of the previous value that may have surpassed 10, try for instance with `[1,2,1,3,6,2,1,5,1,1]`

Comment: It requires a loop regardless.  But for speed you want to loop in fast compiled code.  For inherently sequential tasks like this the stock tools of numpy are more limited.

Comment: It's not clear to me what is actually being asked, i.e. why does @Brenlla's suggestion not provide a route to a good, fast answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one with numba and array-initialization -

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def cumsum_breach_numba2(x, target, result):
    total = 0
    iterID = 0
    for i,x_i in enumerate(x):
        total += x_i
        if total >= target:
            result[iterID] = i
            iterID += 1
            total = 0
    return iterID

def cumsum_breach_array_init(x, target):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    result = np.empty(len(x),dtype=np.uint64)
    idx = cumsum_breach_numba2(x, target, result)
    return result[:idx]
```

**Timings**

Including [`@piRSquared's solutions`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56904650/) and using the benchmarking setup from the same post -

```
In [58]: np.random.seed([3, 1415])
    ...: x = np.random.randint(100, size=1000000).tolist()

# @piRSquared soln1
In [59]: %timeit list(cumsum_breach(x, 10))
10 loops, best of 3: 73.2 ms per loop

# @piRSquared soln2
In [60]: %timeit cumsum_breach_numba(np.asarray(x), 10)
10 loops, best of 3: 69.2 ms per loop

# From this post
In [61]: %timeit cumsum_breach_array_init(x, 10)
10 loops, best of 3: 39.1 ms per loop
```

**Numba : Appending vs. array-initialization**

For a closer look at how the array-initialization helps, which seems be the big difference between the two numba implementations, let's time these on the array data, as the array data creation was in itself heavy on runtime and they both depend on it -

```
In [62]: x = np.array(x)

In [63]: %timeit cumsum_breach_numba(x, 10)# with appending
10 loops, best of 3: 31.5 ms per loop

In [64]: %timeit cumsum_breach_array_init(x, 10)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.8 ms per loop
```

To force the output to have it own memory space, we can make a copy. Won't change the things in a big way though -

```
In [65]: %timeit cumsum_breach_array_init(x, 10).copy()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.67 ms per loop
```

Comment: It probably won't make much of a difference but I think to be entirely fair you should return a copy of `result[:idx]` to avoid leaking the memory of `result[idx:]`.

Comment: Great answer!  Not surprised  but just saying

Comment: @piRSquared Surely motivated by yours. Think such a array-initialization based one could be used for numba solutions that need to otherwise use appending when the output array size isn't known before-hand. And also, array data works better with numba. So, these two are the learnings from this Q&A.

Comment: Yeah great technique. I’ll be using it

Answer (score 13):

A fun method

```
sumlm = np.frompyfunc(lambda a,b:a+b if a < 10 else b,2,1)
newx=sumlm.accumulate(x, dtype=np.object)
newx
array([1, 3, 4, 7, 10, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10], dtype=object)
np.nonzero(newx==10)

(array([4, 9]),)
```

Comment: Check with `np.random.seed([3, 1415]); x = np.random.randint(100, size=1_000_000).tolist()`

Comment: In other testing `frompyfunc` tends to be 2x faster than more explicit python loops.

Comment: I didn't realize that `frompyfunc` produced a `ufunc` with methods like `accumulate`.

Comment: @hpaulj ah just find out it in the morning :-)

Answer (score 10):

Loops are **not** always bad (especially when you need one).  Also, There is no tool or algorithm that will make this quicker than O(n).  So let's just make a good loop.

#### Generator Function

```
def cumsum_breach(x, target):
    total = 0
    for i, y in enumerate(x):
        total += y
        if total >= target:
            yield i
            total = 0

list(cumsum_breach(x, 10))

[4, 9]
```

---

#### Just In Time compiling with Numba

Numba is a third party library that needs to be installed.
Numba can be persnickety about what features are supported.  But this works.
Also, as pointed out by Divakar, Numba performs better with arrays

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def cumsum_breach_numba(x, target):
    total = 0
    result = []
    for i, y in enumerate(x):
        total += y
        if total >= target:
            result.append(i)
            total = 0

    return result

cumsum_breach_numba(x, 10)
```

---

#### Testing the Two

Because I felt like it `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

**Setup**

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
x0 = np.random.randint(100, size=1_000_000)
x1 = x0.tolist()
```

**Accuracy**

```
i0 = cumsum_breach_numba(x0, 200_000)
i1 = list(cumsum_breach(x1, 200_000))

assert i0 == i1
```

**Time**

```
%timeit cumsum_breach_numba(x0, 200_000)
%timeit list(cumsum_breach(x1, 200_000))

582 µs ± 40.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
64.3 ms ± 5.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Numba was on the order of 100 times faster.

For a more true apples to apples test, I convert a list to a Numpy array

```
%timeit cumsum_breach_numba(np.array(x1), 200_000)
%timeit list(cumsum_breach(x1, 200_000))

43.1 ms ± 202 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
62.8 ms ± 327 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Which brings them to about even.

Comment: This should be fast enough. In the case of non-negative array, we can make it faster with break when `total > 10`.

Comment: May speed up by numba :-) BTW happy 7-4

Comment: @piRSquared that is great sir :-)

Comment: Hi Sir , could you please testing the speed , would like to know how bad frompyfunc on timing compare with numba .

Comment: @piRSquared Convert to array and then feed it to numba. See the magic!

Comment: @Divakar ahh yes.  Thank you.  Interestingly, The generator version does better with a `list` and Numba better with the `array`

Comment: @piRSquared The cost of converting to array is not huge. So, it's not bad when summed up.

Comment: @Divakar pls look into this question. I tried to solve by referring above solution. But I could not...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61346334/groupby-cumulative-in-pandas-then-update-using-numpy-based-specific-condition