# How to iterate an arbitrary function using vectorisation

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I would like to iterate a given function in a pandas dataframe without using a for loop, i.e using vectorisation.

**I have already written a for loop for this function** but I would like to improve the efficiency of this output.

```
def f(x,y,operation):
    if operation=='add':
        return x+y
    elif operation=='power':
        return x**y
    else:
        print('type can only be power or add')
df = pd.DataFrame({
              'first_entry':[1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
              'operation':[np.nan,'plus','power','plus','plus'],
              'operand':[np.nan,3,2,4,1]
              })
first_entry operation operand       expected_result
1           NA        NA            1
NA          plus      3             4 (= 1+3)
NA          power     2             16 (=4**2)
NA          plus      4             20 (=16+4)
NA          plus      1             21 (=20+1)
```

I want to return 
`pd.Series(1,4,16,20,21)`, i.e. iterate `f` over the dataframe

Alternative question:
Suppose now

```
def g(x,y,operation):
    if operation=='relative':
        return x*(1+y)
    elif operation=='absolute':
        return x+y
    else:
        print('type can only be relative or absolute')
```

Can I write a function with list comprehension to give the expected result?

```
first_entry operation operand       expected_result
1           NA            NA            1
NA          relative      3             4 (= 1*(3+1)
NA          absolute      2             6 (=4+2)
NA          relative      4             30 (=6*(4+1)
NA          absolute      1             31 (=30+1)
```

Comment: Are you looking for [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)?

Comment: Apply will not work iteratively.
I know that, for example, .cumsum() is iterative, so I want to iterate with a different function effectively.

Comment: @rafaelc is it possible using list comprehension? is cumsum() not a vectorisable function which depends on the value of the previous computation

Comment: I agree with @rafaelc, this is hard to vectorize because of the updated value for each iteration. If you are interested in a _non vectorized_ solution, I can post one.

Comment: in my actual example, the function f(a,b,operation) returns a+b for operation==operation1, and a*(1+b) for operation==operation2. Do you think this can be done with list comprehension, and if so, how?

Comment: I think the only *major* gain you may get here is using `numba`, if that's even possible for such calculations. I have no experience, so just guessing but that tends to works for simple iterative calculations like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904390/restart-cumsum-and-get-index-if-cumsum-more-than-value

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the relationship between a, b, c directly. But you could use Pandas `apply` function [Apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) or [Apply Map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)?

On a very high level, have something like:

```
def f(row):
    if row["type"] == "add":
        return row["a"] + row["b"]
    elif row["type"] == "power":
        return row["a"] ** row["b"]

df["res"] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

This assumes your columns are named "a", "b", and "type" respectively.

Comment: this will apply the function f to each row.
I want to iterate f over each entry in the results column