# pandas row wise sum when when consecutive column value is less than a certain number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1     col2    col3
 A       34       1
 B       86       2
 A       53       21
 C       24       33
 B       21       2
 C       11       1
```

Now I want to add col1 and  col2 values row wise where consecutive col3 values are less than 3, so the final data frame would look like,

```
 col1    col2
   A      120
   A       53
   C       24
   B       32
```

I could do this using a for loop and comparing it with the previous row, but the execution time will be huge, looking for some pandas shortcuts to do this most efficiently.

Comment: This cumsum with limit problem right ?

Comment: If @YOBEN_S is right, then looping **is** the way to go.

Comment: Maybe help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62585727/how-to-group-based-on-cumulative-sum-that-resets-on-a-condition/62585983#62585983

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cumsum` to get consecutive blocks of value `<=3`:

```
s = df.col3.ge(3)

# print `s.cumsum()` and `s` to see details
df.groupby([s.cumsum(),s], as_index=False).agg({'col1':'first','col2':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2
0    A   120
1    A    53
2    B    32
3    C    24
```

Comment: col3 to 1,1,21,33,1,21?