# Can I resample based on a column which is different from datetime index column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

For example , I have a "datetime" column and "Volume of shares transacted" column. I would like to resample the data everytime a million shares are transacted based on an integer or float datatype column (which is NOT datetime column), "Volume of shares transacted" . I am using Pandas data frame for this.

Comment: Sounds like you want some sort of cumulative sum among rows that resets after a threshold is reached to get the groups? It's a complicated problem, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904390/restart-cumsum-and-get-index-if-cumsum-more-than-value should be useful.

Comment: What do you mean by "resample"? Are you trying to split the df?