# Cumulative sum of a pandas column until a maximum value is met, and average adjacent rows

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum, weighted-average

I'm a biology student who is fairly new to python and was hoping someone might be able to help with a problem I have yet to solve

With some subsequent code I have created a pandas dataframe that looks like the example below:

```
Distance.     No. of values        Mean rSquared
    1                   500                  0.6
    2                    80                  0.3
    3                    40                  0.4
    4                    30                  0.2
    5                    50                  0.2
    6                    30                  0.1
```

I can provide my previous code to create this dataframe, but I didn't think it was particularly relevant.

I need to sum the **number of values** column until I achieve a value >= 100; and then combine the data of the rows of the adjacent columns, taking the weighted average of the distance and mean r2 values, as seen in the example below

```
Mean Distance.             No. Of values             Mean rSquared
1                          500                       0.6
(80*2+40*3)/120            (80+40) = 120             (80*0.3+40*0.4)/120
(30*4+50*5+30*6)/110       (30+50+30) = 110          (30*0.2+50*0.2+30*0.1)/110

etc...
```

I know pandas has it's `.cumsum` function, which I might be able to implement into a `for` loop with an `if` statement that checks the upper limit and resets the sum back to 0 when it is greater than or equal to the upper limit. However, I haven't a clue how to average the adjacent columns.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: With this type of threshold, you'd be better off writing a for loop.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating what would need to go into that for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code snippet to solve your problem.

```
# First, compute some weighted values
df.loc[:, "weighted_distance"] = df["Distance"] * df["No. of values"]
df.loc[:, "weighted_mean_rSquared"] = df["Mean rSquared"] * df["No. of values"]


min_threshold = 100
indexes = []
temp_sum = 0

# placeholder for final result
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
columns = ["Distance", "No. of values", "Mean rSquared"]

# reseting index to make the 'df' usable in following output
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

# main loop to check and compute the desired output
for index, _ in df.iterrows():
    temp_sum += df.iloc[index]["No. of values"]
    indexes.append(index)

    # if the sum exceeds 'min_threshold' then do some computation
    if temp_sum >= min_threshold:
        temp_distance = df.iloc[indexes]["weighted_distance"].sum() / temp_sum
        temp_mean_rSquared = df.iloc[indexes]["weighted_mean_rSquared"].sum() / temp_sum
    
        # create temporary dataframe and concatenate with the 'final_df'
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[temp_distance, temp_sum, temp_mean_rSquared]], columns=columns)
        final_df = pd.concat([final_df, temp_df])
    
        # reset the variables
        temp_sum = 0
        indexes = []
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, I didn't think I was going to end up with an answer so I ended up stumbling around in Python and came up with a similar solution, as such I'm giving the answer to you, thanks again! Edit: Didn't initially finish the comment as I didn't know enter submitted the comment (d'oh)

Answer (score 1):

Numpy has a function [`numpy.frompyfunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html) You can use that to get the cumulative value based on a threshold.

Here's how to implement it. With that, you can then figure out the index when the value goes over the threshold. Use that to calculate the `Mean Distance` and `Mean rSquared` for the values in your original dataframe.

I also leveraged @sujanay's idea of calculating the weighted values first.

```
c = ['Distance','No. of values','Mean rSquared']
d = [[1,500,0.6], [2,80,0.3], [3,40,0.4],
     [4,30,0.2], [5,50,0.2], [6,30,0.1]]

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)

#calculate the weighted distance and weighted mean squares first
df.loc[:, "w_distance"] = df["Distance"] * df["No. of values"]
df.loc[:, "w_mean_rSqrd"] = df["Mean rSquared"] * df["No. of values"]

#use numpy.frompyfunc to setup the threshold condition

sumvals = np.frompyfunc(lambda a,b: a+b if a <= 100 else b,2,1)

#assign value to cumvals based on threshold
df['cumvals'] = sumvals.accumulate(df['No. of values'], dtype=np.object)

#find out all records that have >= 100 as cumulative values
idx = df.index[df['cumvals'] >= 100].tolist()

#if last row not in idx, then add it to the list
if (len(df)-1) not in idx: idx += [len(df)-1]

#iterate thru the idx for each set and calculate Mean Distance and Mean rSquared
i = 0
for j in idx:
    df.loc[j,'Mean Distance'] = (df.iloc[i:j+1]["w_distance"].sum() / df.loc[j,'cumvals']).round(2)
    df.loc[j,'New Mean rSquared'] = (df.iloc[i:j+1]["w_mean_rSqrd"].sum() / df.loc[j,'cumvals']).round(2)
    i = j+1

print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
   Distance  No. of values  ...  Mean Distance  New Mean rSquared
0         1            500  ...           1.00               0.60
1         2             80  ...            NaN                NaN
2         3             40  ...           2.33               0.33
3         4             30  ...            NaN                NaN
4         5             50  ...            NaN                NaN
5         6             30  ...           5.00               0.17
```

If you want to extract only the records that are non NaN, you can do:

```
final_df = df[df['Mean Distance'].notnull()]
```

This will result in:

```
   Distance  No. of values  ...  Mean Distance  New Mean rSquared
0         1            500  ...           1.00               0.60
2         3             40  ...           2.33               0.33
5         6             30  ...           5.00               0.17
```

I looked up BEN_YO's implementation of numpy.frompyfunc. The original SO post can be found here. [Restart cumsum and get index if cumsum more than value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904390/restart-cumsum-and-get-index-if-cumsum-more-than-value/56904899#56904899)

Answer (score 1):

If you figure out the grouping first, pandas `groupby`-functionality will do a lot of the remaining work for you. A loop is appropriate to get the grouping (unless somebody has a clever one-liner):

```
>>> groups = []
>>> group = 0
>>> cumsum = 0
>>> for n in df["No. of values"]:
...     if cumsum >= 100:
...         cumsum = 0
...         group = group + 1
...     cumsum = cumsum + n
...     groups.append(group)
>>>
>>> groups
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Before doing the grouped operations you need to use the No. of values information to get the weighting in:

```
df[["Distance.", "Mean rSquared"]] = df[["Distance.", "Mean rSquared"]].multiply(df["No. of values"], axis=0)
```

Now get the sums like this:

```
>>> sums = df.groupby(groups)["No. of values"].sum()
>>> sums
0    500
1    120
2    110
Name: No. of values, dtype: int64
```

And finally the weighted group averages like this:

```
>>> df[["Distance.", "Mean rSquared"]].groupby(groups).sum().div(sums, axis=0)
   Distance.  Mean rSquared
0   1.000000       0.600000
1   2.333333       0.333333
2   5.000000       0.172727
```