# Is there a way to use cumsum with a threshold to create bins?

Tags: pandas

Is there a way to use numpy to add numbers in a series up to a threshold, then restart the counter. The intention is to form groupby based on the categories created.

```
  amount       price
0   27   22.372505
1   17  126.562276
2   33  101.061767
3   78  152.076373
4   15  103.482099
5   96   41.662766
6  108   98.460743
7  143  126.125865
8   82   87.749286
9   70   56.065133
```

The only solutions I found iterate with .loc which is slow. I tried building a solution based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56904899:

```
 sumvals = np.frompyfunc(lambda a,b: a+b if a <= 100 else b,2,1)
    df['cumvals'] = sumvals.accumulate(df['amount'], dtype=np.object)
```

The use-case is to find the average price of every 75 sold amounts of the thing.

Comment: can you show the expected output, not very clear from your question

Comment: You're right - there were 2 different questions. I wanted to average the price every 75 sold amounts, but then I realized this may involve splitting threshold rows into two, and decided to instead simplify it by creating a group when amount goes over 75. Thanks for being thorough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution #1** Interpreting the following one way will get my solution below: *"The use-case is to find the average price of every 75 sold amounts of the thing."* If you are trying to do this calculation the "hard way" instead of `pd.cut`, then here is a solution that will work well but the speed / memory will depend on the `cumsum()` of the `amount` column, which you can find out if you do `df['amount'].cumsum()`. The output will take about 1 second per every 10 million of the `cumsum`, as that is how many rows is created with `np.repeat`. Again, this solution is not horrible if you have less than ~10 million in cumsum (1 second) or even 100 million in cumsum (~10 seconds):

```
i = 75
df = np.repeat(df['price'], df['amount']).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
g = df.index // i
df = df.groupby(g)['price'].mean()
df.index = (df.index * i).astype(str) + '-' + (df.index * i +75).astype(str)
df
Out[1]: 
0-75        78.513748
75-150     150.715984
150-225     61.387540
225-300     67.411182
300-375     98.829611
375-450    126.125865
450-525    122.032363
525-600     87.326831
600-675     56.065133
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

---

**Solution #2** (I believe this is wrong but keeping just in case)
I do not believe you are tying to do it this way, which was my initial solution, but I will keep it here in case, as you haven't included expected output. You can create a new series with `cumsum` and then use `pd.cut` and pass `bins=np.arange(0, df['Group'].max(), 75)` to create groups of cumulative 75. Then, groupby the groups of cumulative 75 and take the mean. Finally, use `pd.IntervalIndex` to clean up the format and change to a sting:

```
df['Group'] = df['amount'].cumsum()
s = pd.cut(df['Group'], bins=np.arange(0, df['Group'].max(), 75))
df = df.groupby(s)['price'].mean().reset_index()
df['Group'] = pd.IntervalIndex(df['Group']).left.astype(str) + '-' + pd.IntervalIndex(df['Group']).right.astype(str)
df
Out[1]: 
     Group       price
0     0-75   74.467390
1   75-150  101.061767
2  150-225  127.779236
3  225-300   41.662766
4  300-375   98.460743
5  375-450         NaN
6  450-525  126.125865
7  525-600   87.749286
```

Comment: You're right - there were 2 different questions. I wanted to average the price every 75 sold amounts, but then I realized this may involve splitting threshold rows into two, and decided to instead simplify it by creating a group when amount goes over 75. Thanks for being thorough!