# Sequential calculation of the sum of np array elements without using loops with a condition for the sum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to write a code **without loops** (and preferably without lambda function) for a numpy array that calculates the sum of elements up to current element of the array, and replaces element with zero if the sum is greater than a certain value, and starts counting the sum again from the next element.

**example**:

np array from 1 to 10 and sum limited to 10.

I can do something like this through a loop, but how without it?

input is:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

```
array = np.arange(1,10)
sum_arr = 0

for i in range(len(array)):
    sum_arr += array[i]
    if sum_arr > 10:
        sum_arr = 0
        array[i] = 0
```

output is:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0]

Comment: You can't avoid loops; the best you can do in `numpy` is to move the loops into compiled code.  And as the answers show, the closest operation is `cumsum`, or some other form of `ufunc.accumulate`.  But "resetting" the sum periodically requires some creative thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Building on top of @*BENY's* [*answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56904899/16120011) to use numpy's [*boolean array indexing*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) :

```
array = np.arange(1, 10)

L = 10 # <- change the limit here
​
cs_func = np.frompyfunc(lambda a,b: a+b if a < L+1 else b, 2, 1)
    
array[cs_func.accumulate(array) > L] = 0
```

Output :

```
>>> print(array)
​
# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0])
```

*Intermediates* :

```
>>> print(cs_func.accumulate(array))

#array([1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 6, 13, 8, 17], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This use of `frompyfunc` probably isn't a lot faster than the equivalent loop, but it is a nice use of its `accumulate`, implementing a complex version of `cumsum`.

Comment: `%%timeit` shows that the OP's loop is about *~x4* faster than the func routine approach but the latter is a lot more fancier, I agree ;). But I still don't know why the OP are trying to avoid loops and the funny thing is they updated their question (*to exclude lambdas too*) right after my answer..

Answer (score 1):

The numpy approach I show later in my answer is actually *slower* than just iterating over the array. You will get the best performance by simply using `numba` to pre-compile your loopy function:

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def andrey_numba(array, limit):
    sum_arr = 0

    for i in range(len(array)):
        sum_arr += array[i]
        if sum_arr > limit:
            sum_arr = 0
            array[i] = 0
    return array
```

[Timeless's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75967211/843953) creative application of `np.ufunc.accumulate` is about as fast as your loopy approach.

[image]

---

I can't think of a way to avoid loops completely, but you could loop until the `cumsum` contains any elements greater than 10, and subtract the sum of the previous elements from the remaining array:

```
def pranav(array, limit):
    cumsum_arr = array.cumsum()

    over_limit = cumsum_arr > limit
    iters = 0 # Just to keep track of how many iterations
    while over_limit.any():
        iters += 1
        over_limit_index = over_limit.argmax() # https://stackoverflow.com/a/48360950/843953
        array[over_limit_index] = 0
        cumsum_arr[over_limit_index:] -= cumsum_arr[over_limit_index]
        over_limit = cumsum_arr > limit

    return array
```

Which leaves you with the desired `array`, in fewer `iters` (`3` instead of `9`):

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0])
```

However, it actually takes *more* time, since you end up doing a lot more calculations in each loop. IMO this is a good illustration that not everything is made more efficient by using numpy. There are probably ways to gain performance by tweaking my numpy code, but I decided it's not worth it since numba and native-python perform well enough.

Answer (score 0):

With no loops, a *global* and built-ins only:

```
sum = 0
def foo(x):
    global sum
    sum += x
    if sum > 10:
        sum = 0
        return 0
    return x
print(list(map(foo, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0]
```

Performance:

[image]